# Gallery Image File Exists but Bitmap decode file is null

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to show an image picked from the gallery using the uri path returned by `OnActivityResult`.The file exists and it is either a `.png` or `.jpg` format but `Bitmap.decodeFile()` is always null or for some pictures(facebook messenger saved) it's showin an `Access denied error`. What am I doing wrong?

I did read all of the related topics.

I don't want to use the `openStream` method which was working, or the `imageView.setImageURI` option which was also working.

Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

MainActivity onCreate:

```
// required by Android 6.0 +
        checkPermissions(getApplicationContext());
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent gallery =
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGES);
            }
        });
```

MainActivity onActivitiyResult:

```
@Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGES && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

                String imagePath = "";
                Uri targetUri = data.getData();
                if (data.toString().contains("content:")) {
                    imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(targetUri);
                } else if (data.toString().contains("file:")) {
                    imagePath = targetUri.getPath();
                } else {
                    imagePath = null;
                }

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

                Log.d("Image",imagePath);

                File thePath = new File(imagePath);

                if(thePath.exists()){
                    Log.d("Image", "exists");
                }

                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(thePath.getAbsolutePath());
                if(myBitmap == null)
                Log.d("Image","bummer");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Something went wrong");
            }
        }

        public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null,
                        null);
                int column_index = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

First, Android is case-sensitive, so your `<uses-permission>` elements are wrong. Replace `ANDROID.PERMISSION` with `android.permission`.

Second, there is no requirement for your `getRealPathFromURI()` method to work on all devices for all images. Replace:

```
            String imagePath = "";
            Uri targetUri = data.getData();
            if (data.toString().contains("content:")) {
                imagePath = getRealPathFromURI(targetUri);
            } else if (data.toString().contains("file:")) {
                imagePath = targetUri.getPath();
            } else {
                imagePath = null;
            }

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            Log.d("Image",imagePath);

            File thePath = new File(imagePath);

            if(thePath.exists()){
                Log.d("Image", "exists");
            }

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(thePath.getAbsolutePath());
            if(myBitmap == null)
            Log.d("Image","bummer");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

with:

```
            Uri targetUri = data.getData();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
            if(myBitmap == null)
            Log.d("Image","bummer");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Eventually, use an image-loading library (e.g., Picasso, Glide) or otherwise move that work to a background thread.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your suggestions. I do plan on moving this to a background thread. Regarding your uri answer, I get an error while using `decodeStream(targetUri)` as it expects an InputStream and gets an URI.

Comment: @Codenthusiastic: Whoops, sorry, I forgot to open the stream on the `Uri`. I have fixed the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get it working. I had no idea `decodeStream` and `decodeFile` are so similar. Everything is working now, but please add a try-catch block as well so people who find this code will have it working the first time.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to get the details of the image file which was selected from the gallery? It would help me a lot. I'll continue looking in the meantime.

Comment: @Codenthusiastic: Sorry, but I do not know what you mean by "the details of the image file".

Comment: The metadata, using the ExifInterface. If I use it with an inputStream I cannot target lower APIs than 24.

Comment: @Codenthusiastic: You should be using [the support edition of ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html), from the `com.android.support:exifinterface` artifact, which works back to API Level 15 or so.

Comment: I think I am using that: `compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:26.1.0' ` and here is my code for initialising it  `ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));`, but I get the API warning.

Comment: @Codenthusiastic: Make sure your `import` is for `android.support.media.ExifInterface`.

Comment: Thank you. That was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap.decodeFile() is always null
```

If the bitmap would become too big for available memory then decodeFile() returns null. Like decodeStream() will do then.

Try with a smaller picture. Or scale down while loading.

Comment: `decodeStream()' doesn't return null, like I said in the question, if I use that it is going to work.