# ExifInterface Title always null

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the title of an image using the [ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html#TAG_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION) and the `TAG_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION`, but I always get it null. It is working for latitude and longitude or other fields, but not this one.

```
    ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
    Log.d("Image", exifInterface.getAltitude(0)+" and latitude "+ exifInterface.getLatLong()[0]);
    Log.d("Image", exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION));
```

This would output:

```
-0.0 and latitude 53.38388888888889
null
```

Why is this the case? When I click details on the image I can clearly see the title as being "20171213 ...".

Comment: Title ? `"20171213 ` That looks more like a date. Where are you trying to extract a 'title'?

Comment: It looks as if you try to determine the name of the file?

Comment: @greenapps it does look like a date. It is how the camera photos are being saved. And yes, I guess the name of the file is the title in this case. But in the details window title is available. Just open an image and click on details.

Comment: `I can clearly see the title as being "20171213 ...".` Why are you too lazy to post a full file name including extension? Its not a title. It's a file name.

Comment: Ok, next time I'll post the image too. Sorry for being that lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this the case?

Whatever app created the image did not fill in that tag.

> When I click details on the image I can clearly see the title as being "20171213 ...".

Assuming that this question is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47782954/115145), you can wrap the `Uri` in a `DocumentFile` [using `fromSingleUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html#fromSingleUri(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)), then call `getName()` on the `DocumentFile` to get a "display name" associated with the content at that `Uri`.

Comment: Thank you. You re everywhere. I'll give it a go now.

Comment: Thank you. It is working indeed working. After reading the documentation, I was expecting that by using the `TAG_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION` attribute I would get the title of the image, as it was present in the metadata of the image.

Comment: @Codenthusiastic: Did you use `exiftool` or something to examine the metadata?

Comment: No, I just assumed that everything in the details tab would be part of it xD I'm obviously wrong.